# Gutenberg ToggleControl won't visually toggle

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I had a ToggleControl on a block that appears in the *InspectorControls* area. It is by default *on*. When I try to set it using the type of **boolean** it would not save the state properly. When trying to toggle it, it would remain as "*on*" but the help text would change as if it were *off*. When saving changes and reloading, the toggle would be back to *on*.

```
const defaults: {
    autoplay: {
        type: 'boolean',
        meta: 'autoplay',
        default: true
    }
}

....  

<ToggleControl
    label={__('Autoplay')}
    help={attributes.autoplay ? __('Slideshow will start playing automatically', 'five') : __('User will have to cycle slideshow manually', 'five')}
    checked={(attributes.autoplay || defaults.autoplay.default)}
    onChange={() => {
        setAttributes({
            autoplay: !attributes.autoplay
        });
    }}
/>
```

However, if I change that input to be a **string** and do the boolean handling myself it toggles the input correctly and saves the state:

```
const defaults: {
    autoplay: {
        type: 'boolean',
        meta: 'autoplay',
        default: true
    }
}

....

<ToggleControl
    label={__('Autoplay')}
    help={attributes.autoplay == 'true' ? __('Slideshow will start playing automatically', 'five') : __('User will have to cycle slideshow manually', 'five')}
    checked={(attributes.autoplay || defaults.autoplay.default) == 'true'}
    onChange={(nextValue) => {
        setAttributes({
            autoplay: nextValue ? 'true' : 'false'
        });
    }} 
/>
```

This works, but requires extra characters when checking for truthy when rendering.  I could probably make this a little easier by just using a number and using 0 and 1, but that's not the point.
Am I missing something with the boolean type, or is this a bug in Gutenberg?

WP Version: 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Your condition inside `checked` attribute is wrong because it is always evaluating to `true`. While your help text don't have any of that condition, toggling of help text depends on `attributes.autoplay` which you are changing inside `onChange` attribute.

So the solution is to change your condition on `checked` attribute.

Attributes inside `registerBlockType` can define default values by using `default` key inside any attribute so the recommended way is to use that. ([default attribute example from wordpress cover block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/cover/index.js))

Comment: if you are correct about `checked` attribute evaluating to `true`, then why does version 2 of they way I'm doing it work as expected? I am doing the exact same logic (I believe) just with checking for a string value of `true` instead of a boolean.